# Bash script terminates on grep statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Having trouble understanding why my bash script terminates abrubtly

```
echo "Checking for ANY QUERY"
dig +short $MYHOSTWITHOUTWWW  any | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'  > $HOME/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP-anyquery.txt
ANYQUERY_STATUS=`grep -iwo 'disabled' $HOME/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP-anyquery.txt`

if [[ "$ANYQUERY_STATUS" = "disabled"  ]]; 
then
    echo "disabled" > $HOME/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP-anyquerybug.txt
else
    echo "enabled" > $HOME/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP-anyquerybug.txt
fi

echo "Checking for Generic top level domains availabilty"
touch  $HOME/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP-domain-gtld.txt
```

However, the program stops and exits at the 'ANYQUERY_STATUS=`grep -iwo 'disabled' statement. It does not follow through executing the rest of the script.

Any help will be highly appreciated here.

Comment: How are you running the script? Is this the whole script? No `set -e` or `bash -e`?

Comment: The capturing of all output into files and further into variables is clumsy and unidiomatic. Do you really require for all these files to be created, or is ths because you aren't very familiar with shell scripting yet?

Comment: Try to use double quotation mark embrace the path for `grep`. And did any error message reveal?

Comment: Its part of the script, tried the double quotes too...but it returns with + ANYQUERY_STATUS= and exits out. The capturing of output into files and vars is a requirement of the project. not much i can do about that.

Comment: I have tried replacing the string comparison with exit code comparison - if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]];
still no luck it doesnt reach this statement. terminates at the grep statement

Comment: Have you tested that `grep` statement by itself?  What did it output?

Comment: Can you do `echo $-` before the `ENTQUERY_STATUS` line and post the output? Btw, it's easier to just write `if grep -qiwo disabled <file>; then ....`

Comment: Run the script like ksh -x ./your_Script.sh and verify where exactly it is failing

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: With long file names, don't repeat yourself.  Store that string in a variable (do not call it PATH).

Comment: Also, try `if ! grep -iow disabled "$input_file"; then echo enabled; fi > "$output_file"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grep` command is returning exit status 1 to indicate when no lines matched and this is causing the variable assignment to fail. It is better to execute the command directly in the script and then use `$?`.

Change the logic of your script so that you can use the status directly:

```
grep -iwo 'disabled' $HOME/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP/$MYHOST-$MYTIMESTAMP-anyquery.txt
if [[ $? = 0 ]];
```

Comment: `if` by definition runs a command and examines its exit code to decide whether to take the `then` branch or the `else` branch. Anything that looks like `command; if [ $? = 0 ]` is better written `if command` and you should generally almost never need to examine `$?` directly.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense. Ty triplee for the input.

Comment: Making code more readable by separating as I did shouldn’t be discounted.